# How to select nth element from all the keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
d = {key: [val1, val2, val3....], key2: [valx, valy, valz, ...], 
key3: [vala, valb, valc, ...], 
....}
```

If I want to print the key and the select the second element for all the keys, meaning in this example, I want to show:

```
key: val2 
key2: valy
key3: valb
```

What do I write?

Comment: Hmmm. Well what have you tried?

Comment: @Eric Does my answer fulfill your requirements?

Comment: Yes, I think your solution is quite simple and it's something that I can use.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of printing, if I just want to create a new dictionary with only the keys and the second element, how would I go back doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to take second value then refer below code

```
d = {'key': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], 'key2': ['valx', 'valy', 'valz'], 'key3': ['vala', 'valb', 'valc']}

for i in d:
    print(i + ' : ' + d[i][1])
```

It's Tested code, You can replace d[i][**1**] with your required position such as If you want 5th value then use 4, As list index starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

you need to traverse through the dictionary like this

```
for key in d:
    print(key + ": " + d[key][1])
```

This will print the desired output

```
key: val2 
key2: valy
key3: valb
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
d = {'key':['apples','oranges','banana'],'key2':['mangoes','pineapple','apple']}
for key in d:
    val = d[key]
    print(key,val[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I find `join` always offers a quick solution:

```
print('\n'.join(['{}: {}'.format(
      k, v[1]) for k, v in d.items()]))
```

Alternatively, use the separator offered by `print`:

```
print(*['{}: {}'.format(
      k, v[1]) for k, v in d.items()],
      sep='\n')
```